# Javascript-inject element change listener?

Tags: javascript, xcode, code-injection, javascript-injection

We use KioWare, and want to trigger a local application (which we can do no problem by keybind).  We only want to trigger the keybind when a specific page element changes from "blahblah-hidden" to "blahblah", and repeat whenever this change recurs.

I've got very basic knowledge of javascript, and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I've tried using while(true) and running a repeat check of the element, but this causes a browser white screen, assuming because nothing else can process during the infinite loop?

If there's a way to simply "watch" or "listen" to the element for changes, that would be great.  Again, I have real basic knowledge of javascript and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for event listeners: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom event and dispatch it when you changing the class name in dom. I.e.

```js
const event = new Event('mycustomevent');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('mycustomevent', function (e) { /* Do your logic here */ }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event); // Insert this line when changing element visibility
```

If element class name changed not by you, obviously you must use `MutationObserver`.

```js
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.querySelector('.blahblah-hidden');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: false, subtree: false };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
// Do your logic here
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```